# Problem with the mobius wireframe

Tags: modifiers, wireframe

Hi guys I created a mobius strip and applied a wireframe modifier to it. It seemed like that it became a complicated wireframe because I used the triangular prism to array. However, I just want to keep the three lines and remove the triangle lines. [image: DETAIL] Anyone could help me to figure it out? I am looking forward to your reply![image]

Here is my blender file. [image]

Comment: To create a real Möbius strip your curve has to be tilted...  ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure that what you ask is possible as the *Wireframe* modifier needs faces to work. If you remove the pyramids it deletes the faces of your object. What you can do instead is give a *Bevel* object to your curve object, like this one:

[image]

You can set the resolution of the curve and also the resolution of the bevel object on the top of the *Object Data* panel > *Shape*. It will help to keep the object low-poly if you convert it to mesh (1 means it won't create any vertex between the 2 existing vertices):

[image]

Also don't forget that for the moment the scale of your curve is not 1 and that if you apply it you need to bring the radius of its vertices back to 1.

Comment: Thank you moonboots for your solution! It really works! But if I want to keep the line as three to five faces rather than 32 faces, can bevel also be used? (I want to make the faces as least as possible ^ ^)

Comment: you can choose whatever profile you want if this is what you mean, what do you mean by 32 faces? please share your current file. Keep in mind that you can set the resolution of the curve and also its bevel profile resolution in the Object Data panel > Shape > Resolution

Comment: Thank you moonboots, I am trying to figure out with your suggestion!